# How to download ignition-cmake2 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04, ros, ignition, gazebo-simu

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findignition-cmake2.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "ignition-cmake2", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ignition-cmake2"
  with any of the following names:

    ignition-cmake2Config.cmake
    ignition-cmake2-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ignition-cmake2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "ignition-cmake2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "ignition-cmake2" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/ign-fuel-tools/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and already download "ignition-cmake0".

Comment: What commands are you running that trigger this error?

Comment: $/tmp/ign-fuel-tools/build: cmake ../

Comment: i am using the terminal

Comment: Your question is missing some context: are you building the Ignition Fuel Tools (as described [here](https://ignitionrobotics.org/tutorials/fuel_tools/1.0/md__data_ignition_ign-fuel-tools_tutorials_installation.html))? If so, did you install any dependencies before running `cmake ../`?

Comment: yes as showing in the link (ignition fuel tools),i did install so many dependencies as required in my project

Comment: If you have installed `ignition-cmake2`, then, according to the [package info](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libignition-cmake2-dev/filelist), you should have a file `/usr/share/cmake/ignition-cmake2/ignition-cmake2-config.cmake`. Do you actually have this file?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and I solve mine writing the path of the directory on the Build/CMakeCache in the line where is written NOT FOUND.